# Custom fonts not showing on different platforms/browsers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm currently using the platform Quickbutik to design a website, and I'm using @font-face to import custom fonts as seen below:

```css
       @font-face {
          font-family: 'Gambarino-Regular';
          src: url('../fonts/Gambarino-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
               url('../fonts/Gambarino-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
               url('../fonts/Gambarino-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
               font-weight: 400;
               font-display: swap;
              font-style: normal;
        }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Mona-Sans';
      src:
        url('Mona-Sans.woff2') format('woff2 supports variations'),
        url('Mona-Sans.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
        
      font-weight: 200 900;
      font-stretch: 75% 125%;
    }
```

However, the fonts not visible on other devices and browsers (currently using Chrome on both devices). The image shows what it's supposed to look like:

[image: Correct fonts]

I'm also having fallback fonts (see below), and they are  visible on some devices, and on others they are not.

[image: Correct fonts not visible]

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Mona-Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif !important;
    overflow: overlay;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .font-heading {
    font-family: 'Gambarino-regular', 'Garamond', serif !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 120%;
}
```

How can I correct this issue? Do I need to upload any font files, is there something with the platform/browsers or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You definitely need to upload custom fonts. Check your dev tools network tab for errors. Quite likely you see locally installed versions of the font on your main/delevopment device and wrong/fallback fonts on other devices. You should probaly search for quikbutic specific tutorials how to install/enable custom fonts.